# WPF DataGrid - Change value row by row in "real time"

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm creating this DataGrid:

```
DataTable _dt = new DataTable("MyDataTable");
_dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
_dt.Columns.Add("File", typeof(string));
_dt.Columns.Add("Folder", typeof(string));
_dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
_dt.Columns["ID"].AutoIncrement = true;
_dt.Columns["ID"].AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
_dt.Columns["ID"].AutoIncrementStep = 1;

FilesGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Extended;

FilesGridView.ItemsSource = _dt.DefaultView;
```

and then populating it with a list of file paths.

When I hit the *Process* button, I want to loop through all the rows in the grid and change the value of the Status column, **row by row**.

So I've written this:

```
private void ProcessButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataRowView row in FilesGridView.ItemsSource)
    {
        row["Status"] = "Processing...";
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);    //letting 2 sec pass as a test
    }
}
```

but what happens is that it starts calculating and after 2 seconds * the iterations in the loop are elapsed, the table changes all at once.

What I was looking for was that entering the foreach loop, it was changing the displayed value first row, then waiting 2 sec and changing the displayed value of the second row, and so on.

What am I missing? How do I achieve that?

Comment: After setting the status, try `FilesGridView.Items.Refresh();`

Comment: It's really a poor man's approach doomed to fail, it's certainly best to use a decorator for each row then do that computation in a background task. And putting UI thread to sleep in an UI event handler is what hangs your UI.

Comment: @bolkay that didn't work for some reason.

Comment: @Aybe what I'm showing is actually a test/simulation. In reality, instead of waiting, my code is processing things and I wanted the Status field to inform the user if that file in the list is being processed or it's complete. Also, I'm not familiar with decorators.
What would be an alternative to Sleep so that I see the change row by row?

Comment: I just tried replacing the Sleep bit with a MessageBox (just an even poorer man's test, I know) and it works. So yeah I guess the problem was that Sleep was hanging the UI.

Comment: The application freezes during the time that it takes complete the loop. You want to display the progress on updates while is doing the loop?

Comment: @Marlonchosky yeah exactly.

Comment: @AndreaTassera I answered your question. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: That answer is already a good start, se if you can use an adorner instead of changing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to display the progress on updates while the loop is running, you just need a bit of asynchronous programming. 
Just make your event handler method asynchronous and run the loop inside a Task, like this:

```
private async void Process_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    await Task.Run(async () => {
        foreach (DataRowView row in this.FilesGridView.ItemsSource) {
            row["Status"] = "Processing...";
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
    });
}
```

I tested the code in [this](https://github.com/marlonedu/WpfTests/tree/master/WpfApp14) project. Check the MainWindow. Add some items during execution in the DataGrid and then press the button.

Comment: `await Task.Run` can and should be removed. the only issue was Thread.Sleep

Comment: @ASh Why do you say that? The Task.Run method is a wrapper in case the loop performs a heavy computational task. In the sample code, the Task.Delay just simulates that.